# Proof Verification: Monic Polynomials, Gauss' Lemma and UFDs

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I'm struggling a bit polynomial rings. I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, with quotient field $F$, and let $p(x)$ be a monic polynomial in $R[x]$. Assume that $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$, where $a(x), b(x) \in F[x]$. Prove thatif $a(x) \notin R[x]$, then $R$ isn't a UFD. Use this to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{8}]$ isn't a UFD.

Suggested Proof:

Assume that $R$ is a UFD. Then, by Gauss' Lemma and its corolloaries, $R[x]$ is a UFD. We already know that $F[x]$ is a UFD. Reducing the polynomial $p(x)$ in $R[x]$, we have that,

\begin{align}
p(x) = \prod_{i}^{n} p_i(x) = a(x)b(x), \quad p_i(x) \in R[x] \subset F[x],
\end{align}

where each $p_i(x)$ is irreducible. Since factorization is unique in $F[x]$, we can infer that,

\begin{align}
a(x) = \prod_{i}^{l} p_i(x) a'(x) \quad \text{where} \; 1 \leq l \leq n,
\end{align}

and all units in $F[x]$  or $F^{\times}$ have been subsumed in $a'(x)$. Now, given that $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial, we must have that $a(x)$ is a monic polynomial, which in turn implies that $a'(x)$ is a monic polynomial. This ensures that the gcd of numerators of coefficients in $a'(x)$ is 1 (or not?). If $a'(x)$ contains any fractions, then we can proceed as in Gauss' Lemma, and clear up the fractions in $a'(x)$ to produce,

\begin{align}
a(x) = \prod_{i}^{l} p_i(x) a''(x) \quad \text{where} \; 1 \leq l \leq n,
\end{align}

where not both the $p_i(x)'s$ and $a''(x)$ are in $R[x]$. Hence, we must have that $a(x)$ is in $R[x]$.

I'm not too sure about the proof. I don't seem to have explicitly the monicity of polynomials. Or maybe this is because I proceeded with the contrapositive.

For the example, we can let,

\begin{align}
p(x) = (x^2 - \sqrt{8}) = \underbrace{\Big  ( x + \sqrt{\sqrt{8}} \Big )}_{a(x)} \underbrace{\Big (x - \sqrt{\sqrt{8}} \Big )}_{b(x)}
\end{align}

Clearly, $p(x)$, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are monic, $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{8}][x]$ but $a(x) \notin \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{8}][x]$ since the constant term isn't even in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{8}]$ since $\sqrt{\sqrt{8}} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ implies that $\sqrt{\sqrt{8}} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.